# How to place a left div below main div using css in mobile version

Tags: css, media-queries

I have two divs in my page. #mainContent and #leftcolumn which is in desktop version now. Can I place #leftcolumn div under #mainContent div in mobile version by changing css using media queries? Here is the code.

```
<div id="leftColumn"></div>
<div id="mainContent"></div>

#mainContent{
width:748px;
margin: 0 0 0 192px;
background-color: #fff4dd;
border: 1px solid #d0b281;
border-width: 0px 1px;
padding: 0 0 13px 0;
}

#leftColumn{
width: 180px;
float: left;
padding: 0 3px 0 7px;
margin: 123px 0 0 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is definitely possible- would you be able to create a jsfiddle providing us with this HTML?

Comment: What does your html look like? If left div is under main div in your html strucutre/ordering then yes you can do with css

Comment: actually in the html code the leftcolumn is above maincontent. Is it possible to do with css or do I need to use javascript?

Comment: Also your <div>s are missing closing tags- just to be sure that's not causing you any problems

Comment: I forgot to include the closing tags. Thanks @mk14 . That solved the problem